# Previewing table in ArcGIS Pro without adding to map?

Tags: table, arcgis-pro

In ArcMap I often preview a table by using the Catalog window to right-click it, which opens the Item Description window and enables me to go to the Preview tab.

Is there an equivalent workflow (i.e. one that does not require me to add the table to a map) in ArcGIS Pro to do this?

From what I can see in ArcGIS Pro 1.3.1 the closest thing seems to be using the Project pane to right-click the table but then I have to "Add to Current Map", "Add to New Map" or "Add to New Scene" before I can use the Contents pane to right-click and Open it.

There is an ArcGIS Idea to [Add Stand Alone Data Catalog Like ArcCatalog to ArcGIS Pro](https://geonet.esri.com/ideas/12671-add-stand-alone-data-catalog-to-arcgis-pro-like-arccatalog) which I am reserving my vote on at the moment.  I am hoping for something more like Preview from ArcMap's Item Description in its Catalog window.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is sadly not possible in ArcGIS Pro due to the catalog window not supporting table previews:

[image]
[The ArcGIS Pro help also confirms this:](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/help/projects/preview-data.htm)

```
Note:
Tabular data cannot be previewed at this time.
```

I would not be surprised to see this added to future updates, though, going by the wording and the usefulness of such a feature.